# select random rows for each ID with a condition in sql (Hive)

Tags: sql, hive, sampling, partition

Below is a table that has 85M rows with **~7M distinct product_ids**. The dates range from 1st Jan 2019 to 31st Oct 2019 (10 months in total).

```
product_id    status     date
60151028       LESS    2019-04-04
86069378       MORE    2019-08-12
99660145       LESS    2019-01-06
16775944       LESS    2019-05-12
52801157       LESS    2019-09-06
4493185        LESS    2019-09-13
39917883       LESS    2019-07-03
87716367       MORE    2019-05-24
90785856       MORE    2019-05-15
15412972       SAME    2019-07-11
12236638       SAME    2019-03-23
.
.
.
.
60151028       LESS    2019-10-12
```

I want to generate a random sample for my analysis and I want to select 4 random rows for each ID and status -- for example, I want:

1. 4 rows with an ID 60151028 having status = "LESS"
2. 4 rows with an ID 60151028 having status = "MORE"
3. 4 rows with an ID 60151028 having status = "SAME" and similar goes with all the product IDs-- this means that there are 12 rows with same product ID.

The data should be selected randomly across all the dates within those 10 months. Below is the result view:

```
product_id  status      date
60151028       LESS    2019-04-04
60151028       LESS    2019-07-18
60151028       LESS    2019-09-23
60151028       LESS    2019-01-25
60151028       SAME    2019-05-14
60151028       SAME    2019-10-11
60151028       SAME    2019-03-31
60151028       SAME    2019-08-30
60151028       MORE    2019-04-27
60151028       MORE    2019-09-19
60151028       MORE    2019-10-29
60151028       MORE    2019-06-04
.
.
.
39917883       SAME    2019-08-03
39917883       SAME    2019-02-26
39917883       SAME    2019-10-07
.
.
.
```

I have thought till the below query (Hive), but I am not able to think of how to randomly select rows where the status = "LESS" or "MORE", etc. Any help will be appreciated!!

Also, I know there is a rand() function is hive sql but I do not know how to use it here.

```
select max(case when status = 'LESS' then 1 else 0 end) OVER (PARTITION by product_id) as flg
,detail1.*
from
(
select row_number() OVER
(partition by product_id order by date) as rn
from db.table 
) detail1

UNION ALL

select max(case when status = 'SAME' then 1 else 0 end) OVER (PARTITION by product_id) as flg
,detail2.*
from
(
select row_number() OVER
(partition by product_id order by date) as rn
from db.table  
) detail2

UNION ALL

select max(case when status = 'MORE' then 1 else 0 end) OVER (PARTITION by product_id) as flg
,detail3.*
from
(
select row_number() OVER
(partition by product_id order by date) as rn
from db.table  
) detail3
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `partition by`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*
             row_number() OVER (partition by product_id, status order by rand()) as seqnum
      from db.table  
     ) t
where seqnum <= 4;
```

EDIT:

To get a sample where all statuses have at least 4 rows:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*
             row_number() OVER (partition by product_id, status order by rand()) as seqnum,
             max(ps_cnt) over (partition by product_id) as max_ps_cnt
      from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by product_id, status) as ps_cnt
            from db.table t
           ) t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 4 and max_ps_cnt >= 4;
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this. Below is the result:
```
           product_id    status             date        seq_num
        100011169 MORE 2019-10-16 1
 100011169 MORE 2019-07-29 2
 100011169 MORE 2019-07-22 3
 100011169 MORE 2019-08-27 4
 100011855 LESS 2019-01-01 1
 100011855 LESS 2019-01-02 2
 100011855 LESS 2019-01-13 3
 100011855 LESS 2019-01-04 4
```
Your result is giving out only one status for each product_id. However, I want something like for 100011169 4 of MORE, 4 of LESS and 4 of SAME. so there should be 12 rows for each product id have 4 rows with status = 'MORE'.. and so on.

Comment: @vineet . . . This code should be giving four rows for every product/status combination in the data.  Are you sure you are running this query?

Comment: Hi Gordon! my mistake, yes it is giving out 4 rows for every product status combo. Thank you so much, I really appreciate it. I just found out that there are many product_ids that have only one status all over the 10 month range. Is there a way to only show product_Ids that have all the 3 statuses occurring at lease 4 times in those 10 month range?

Comment: Also, if possible, is there a way to get exact 4 rows for each status(instead of at least 4)?

Comment: @vineet . . . You should really ask a new question.  However, sampling only products that have "enough" rows is within the spirit of the question that you did ask, so I edited the answer.